# Получаю ошибку при попытке добавить систему регистрации и аутентификации пользователей на Django

Tags: python, django, сервер, python-3.6

Прохожу туториал по Django, и застрял в разделе, когда нужно добавить аутентификацию и регистрацию пользователей, хотя все делал по туториалу. Вот ссылка на этот раздел: https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/authentication_authorization

Конкретно о проблеме:

При попытке запустить сервер оно выдает ошибку `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Вот полный текст ошибки:

> Blockquote   File "C:\Users\Admin\django_boys\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 400, in check
> messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
> File "C:\Users\Admin\django_boys\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
> return check_method()
> File "C:\Users\Admin\django_boys\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 401, in check
> messages.extend(self._check_custom_error_handlers())
> File "C:\Users\Admin\django_boys\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 418, in _check_custom_error_handlers
> signature = inspect.signature(handler)
> File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 3130, in signature
> return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
> File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 2879, in from_callable
> return _signature_from_callable(obj, sigcls=cls,
> File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 2330, in _signature_from_callable
> return _signature_from_function(sigcls, obj,
> File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 2194, in _signature_from_function
> parameters.append(Parameter(name, annotation=annotation,
> File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 2517, in **init**
> self._kind = _ParameterKind(kind)
> File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\enum.py", line 360, in **call**
> return cls.**new**(cls, value)
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Я полагаю, что причина ошибки в неправильном синтаксисе, либо в указании пути, либо в неправильно импорте модулей в файле `urls.py`.

Вот его код:

```
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    # и т.п.
    # до добавления последующих 4 строк кода, все работало нормально.
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

1. Изначально Django просто путало две одинаковых названия `views`, поэтому второй `views` переименовал на `auth_views`.
2. Когда поменял, появилась уже эта проблема, о котором и пишу.

Буду рад вашим советам.

ps: уровень владения Django, можно сказать нулевой.

Answer (score 1):

LoginView и LogoutView это имена ваших view-классов, а так же это имена классов реализующих авторизацию и выход с сайта. Вкратце поменяйте названия выше упомянутых классов

Comment: спасибо за ответ) Но я уже решил, т.е. ночью, и вот сейчас утром напишу ответ себе, как решил.

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается проблема была в последней строке, т.е. в :

```
path('', include('blog.urls')),
```

Я поменял аргумента include и получилось вот такой код:

```
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

И проблема была решена.

Не скажу, что это самое правильное и эффективное решение, но если у вас возникнет такая же проблема, поищите причину сначала в include().

И да, полезно будет почитать про роль include().